# simple LINQ refactoring / style

Tags: c#, linq, coding-style, refactoring

As LINQ `Select()` wants a `FUNC<int,T>` as argument, I have to define an unused variable.
I think query syntax makes that clearer in this case.

How do I get rid of any clutter to make that simple and clean to read?

```
var rand = new Random();

//Method syntax

IEnumerable<char> c = Enumerable.Range(0, 10)                          
                                .Select( (p) => (char)('A' + rand.Next(0,26)));
//Query syntax
var c = from counter in Enumerable.Range(0,10)
            select (char)('A' + rand.Next(0,26));
```

Comment: query syntax would get converted as lambda expression eventually

Comment: I appreciate the quick comeback!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks pretty clean and easy to read already.

I don't think you'll get any further, nor that it's worthwhile -- even if you define your own `Select<T, TR>(this T t, Func<TR> f)`, you'll still have to call it as `t.Select(() => ...)` (notice the empty parentheses).

You can explicitly mark an unused variable as `_` though:

```
var c = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(_ => (char)('A' + rand.Next(0, 26)));
```

Or, you can use an added abstraction and hide the projection, say, in a local method:)

```
char RandomChar(int _) => (char)('A' + rnd.Next(0, 26));

var c = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select(RandomChar);
```

Comment: I like the idea with `_` for an unused variable and your extracted Select. I am always unsure if I know all the helpful LINQ ext.-methods. E.g. using Range() as iterator and ignoring the result...

Comment: @FalcoAlexander FYI they're called [Discards](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/discards)